# Solving differential equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have the following differential equation
\begin{align}
  \left[-\partial^{2}_{x}+ x^{2} -1-2\alpha_{+}\right] \left[-\partial^{2}_{x}+ x^{2} -1-2\alpha_{-}\right] \phi(x)=0, \quad \alpha_{\pm}=\dfrac{-1}{2}+\dfrac{E^{2}}{2}\pm \dfrac{\sqrt{a^{4}+(\beta E)^{2}}}{2a^{2}}
  \end{align}
My question is : what is the method used to find the eigenvalues of this equation.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are those paratmetrs?

Comment: Better for Math SE?

Answer (score 1):

This looks too much  like a homework problem to warrant an answer, so I will remind you a couple of facts about the quantum harmonic oscillator and its solutions, the [Hermite functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Hermite_functions) used in physics problems; your posting this here assumes you are intrigued by physics applications. Your second specification appears meaningless without further information.

You are interested for all all eigenfunctions $\phi(x)$ in the kernel of this operator, for allowable constants $\alpha_{\pm}$,
$$
\hat O=  \left[-\partial^{2}_{x}+ x^{2} -1-2\alpha_{+}\right] \left[-\partial^{2}_{x}+ x^{2} -1-2\alpha_{-}\right].
$$
As a physicist, you surely recognize in each square bracket Hermite's operator
$$
D= (-\partial^{2}_{x}+ x^{2} -1)/2~,
$$
trivially related to the oscillator hamiltonian. You know its eigenvalues are the integers, *0,1,2,...,n,...* for eigenfunctions $\psi_n(x)$, the Hermite functions, linked, $D\psi_n = n\psi_n$, but I will not insist on integer *n*s in the absence of further (boundary) information.

Your operator then presents as
$$
\hat O/4=(D-\alpha_+) (D-\alpha_-),
$$
and, acting on these Hermite functions, $\psi_n(x)   = (-1)^n \left (2^n n! \sqrt{\pi} \right)^{- 1/2} e^{ {x^2}/{2}}   \partial_x^n e^{-x^2}$, it yields
$$
(n-\alpha_+)(n-\alpha_-), 
$$
which must vanish for your kernel, so $n=\alpha_{\pm}$ will do.

You have to fuss the details and choices yourself, subject to the physical constraints of your problem, possibly continuing off the integers.